# Django Table2 get value bound column

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I'm confused, please tell me how to get the value of another `Term_Implementation` field in Table.render_foo methods?

[Table.render_foo methods](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/custom-data.html)

[BoundColumn](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/internal.html)

[BoundColumn-getitem](https://django-tables2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/django_tables2/columns/base.html#BoundColumns.__getitem__)

```
class EvensList(IncidentsTable, tables.Table):

    class Meta:
        model = AkpEvents
        
        sequence = ('Term_Implementation', 'Status')

    Term_Implementation = tables.DateColumn(empty_values=(),)

    Status = tables.Column(empty_values=(),)

   def render_Status(self, value, column, columns):
        if value == 'Выполнено':
            column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-success'}}

        elif value == 'В работе':
            column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-warning'}}

        elif columns['Term_Implementation'] <= date.today():
            column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-danger'}}

        else:
            column.attrs = {'td': {'class': ''}}

        return value
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve it, you just had to use the built-in parameter of the `record` function, which returns the entire object.

```
def render_Status(self, value, record, column):
    if value == 'Выполнено':
        column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-success text-center align-middle'}}

    elif value == 'В работе':
        column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-warning text-center align-middle'}}

    elif record.Term_Implementation <= date.today():
        column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'table-danger text-center align-middle'}}

    else:
        column.attrs = {'td': {'class': 'text-center align-middle'}}

    return value
```